# Owl Carousel Items stacking one on each other

Tags: php, css, owl-carousel

I've got problem with Owl Carousel on my site.

I'm using php to generate module that display news board. I wanted them inside carousel, but div "owl items" started to stack on each other.

IDK What to do.
I've tried even just HTML, but to no avail, help.

Here's pic
[WTF going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZm8r.png)

Comment: are u missing any script? jquery maybe? 
can you provide a jsfiddle to analyse your code?

Comment: I have jquery 1.11.2 Is it too outdated for Carousel 2?  I can't provide jsfiddle but I'm not missing anything and it was working on other page.

Comment: is hard to say if you not provide the code @Fadlan

Comment: Ok let me a sec to generate it.